# How to click the right button when there are two buttons with same text

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

There are two buttons both with Login as inner text

```
<div>
      <h3>
        Log in by Email
      </h3>
      <hr />
      Email: <input type="text" name="email"/>
      <button type="submit">
        Login
      </button>
      <h3>
        Log in by something else...
      </h3>
      <button type="submit">
        Login
      </button>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to click the login button next to the email input field

```
const login = await page.locator('button',{hasText:'Login'})
await login.click()
```

And it returns error:

```
locator.click: Error: strict mode violation: "button >> :scope:has-text("Login")" resolved to 2 elements:
        1) <button type="submit">Login</button> aka playwright.$("text=Login >> nth=1")
        2) <button type="submit">Login</button> aka playwright.$("text=Login >> nth=3")
```

I want to ask how can I locate the exact button while they both have the same text.
Thank you

Comment: Be more specific in your locator :) e.g. https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-nth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this works. You can select elements based on the layout.

```
const btnLogin = await page.locator('button:has-text("Login"):near(input[name="email"])')
await btnLogin.click()
```

select button with text "Login" near input field with name "email"

Comment: Thank you, it works. although not sure why it failed for chrome browser, it passed after I add .nth(0).

Answer (score 0):

This should works also

```
const secondLoginBtn = await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Login' }).nth(1);
secondLoginBtn.click(); //the nth(1) select the second button
```